# Keyv + MongoDb TypeError The "id" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, keyv

I'm getting this TypeError while using [Keyv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keyv) and [Keyv/mongo](https://github.com/lukechilds/keyv-mongo).

```
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
```

---

When trying to create a new instance of `Keyv`, I pass in the connection string as instructed.

**Given String Template From MongoDB Atlas**
[image: MongoDB Atlas' Given Connection String Template]

**Keyv Documentation Example On Passing A Connection String**
[image: Keyv Documentation Example Connection String Example]

---

This is my code, I have inserted my password and database name into the given connection string as instructed.

```
const Keyv = require('keyv');
const keyv = new Keyv('mongodb+srv://Elitezen4531:***********@zen.hjg40.mongodb.net/Discord_Zen_Bot?retryWrites=true&w=majority');

keyv.on('error', err => console.error('Keyv connection error:', err));
```

Comment: Have you checked if the library Keyv for mongo supports a connection to replicate set (
`mongodb+srv://`)?

Comment: What version of Keyv are you  using? What version of mongo-native?